# Как сделать анимацию уменьшения и увеличения текста?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview, android-textview

У меня есть textview, который изменяется, как сделать анимацию, чтобы когда длина текста будет слишком большой, текст уменьшился и наоборот?

Answer (score 1):

Делать этого я не рекомендую. setTextSize вызывает requestLayout. При анимировании вы будете вызывать его 60 или 30 раз в секунду, что даже не совсем уж слабых девайсах может вызывать проблемы. Подумайте насколько вам необходимо именно анимировать изменение текста. Если все же необходимо, то вот вариант в порядке увеличения сложности реализации.

1) Вы можете сделать объект ValueAnimator

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
animator.setDuration(500L);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        textView.setTextSize(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
```

2) вариант с объектами Animation, которые описываются в xml. TextSize ими не изменить, но можно изменить scale. Не похоже что вам такой метод подходит, но мало ли, вдруг как-то приспособите.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="0,8"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toYScale="0,8"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="3000">
</scale>


Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
textView.startAnimation(animation);
```

3) Создать кастомный View, в onDraw которого вписывать текст максимальным вмещаемым размером. Благо можно вычислять относительно быстро. Пожалуй, самый адекватный вариант, т.к. изменения размера текста происходят одновременно с изменением размеров View и без необходимости requestLayout. Код вряд ли валидный выйдет, но суть уловить должны.

```
public class MyTextView extends View{
   private String text;
   private int l, t, r, b;
   private float textSize = 10f;
   private boolean changed = true;
   Paint paint; 
   public void setText(String text){
      this.text = text;
      changed = true;
   }
   @Override
   public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b){
       super.layout(l, t, r, b);
       this.l = l;
       this.t = t;
       this.r = r;
       this.b = b;
       changed = true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas cv){
      while(true){
         //paint нужно создать и настроить заранее под себя. Цвет, шрифт и т.п.
         paint.setTextSize(textSize);//ставим текущий размер текста
         Rexct rect = new Rect();
         paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length() - 1, rect); //рассчитывается размер текста и укладывается в rect
         if(r-l<rect.rigth - rect.left || b-t<rect.bottom - rect.top){
             textSize-=0.5f;
         } else {
             break;
         }
      }
      cv.drawText(text,0,0,paint);
   }
}
```

Comment: Есть ли другие способы, возможно использовать не textview, а editview?

Comment: дополнил свой ответ

Comment: А про второе, условно если я запускаю анимация, а потом программно изменяю размер текста, как между этими действиями сделать промежуток времени, я пробовал через таймер, но идея была явно плохой, анимация иногда дёргалась

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:repeatMode="reverse">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:pivotX="15%"
        android:pivotY="15%"
        android:duration="500"
        />

</set>
```

Попробуйте использовать анимацию на подобие этой.

Comment: Пробовал, но помимо неё ещё нужно изменять размер текста, если последовательно запускать анимацию, потом изменение текста, иногда возникают баги анимации

Comment: @Lms Попробуйте поступить хардкорно. Поставить таймер и используйте метод scheduleAtFixedRate для повторение каких то действий через определенный промежуток времени. При каждом вызове увеличивайте размер на немного и получиться аккуратная анимация. Ну это у меня в воображение)) могут возникнуть баги но это идея

Comment: Именно так я и делал, и в рандомные моменты текст дергался, после завершения анимации